# jcarousel does not show after some images

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have the following code with jcarousel but strangely it does not work properly.

If i refresh the page i see black items after some next.
BUT if i hit return on address bar of the browser there is no problem.

How can i fix this?

```
        jQuery("#slider").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        // This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
        wrap: 'both',
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
```

Here is the link to page:
http://kabukweb.com/kum/mimari2.php

Comment: What's it meant to be doing, and how is that different to what it is doing?

Comment: Also, it looks fine to me in Chrome 16, albeit with no carousel effect.

Comment: There is a slightly seen right arrow, if you click it you will see a black image. And hit enter on address bar of chrome you will see all images with no problem
I've checked with chore too but same problem.

Comment: If you refresh the page (cmd+R) you will see the problem again

Answer (score 0):

Your images are cached the second time you go to the page. The first time the black happens because the image is downloading.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've fixed the problem by putting jcarousel code in to $(window).load(function () {});